# Can't access asp:TextBox tag from the C# file : the name 'txtUsername' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Consider the aspx :

**CS.aspx :**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CS.aspx.cs" Inherits="CS" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
        input
        {
            width: 200px;
        }
        table
        {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
        table th
        {
            background-color: #F7F7F7;
            color: #333;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        table th, table td
        {
            padding: 5px;
            border-color: #ccc;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">
                Registration
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Username
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtUsername"
                    runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Password
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtPassword"
                    runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Confirm Password
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:CompareValidator ErrorMessage="Passwords do not match." ForeColor="Red" ControlToCompare="txtPassword"
                    ControlToValidate="txtConfirmPassword" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Email
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Required" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"
                    ControlToValidate="txtEmail" runat="server" />
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
                    ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Invalid email address." />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="RegisterUser" />
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and its C# file : **CS.asps.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class CS : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void RegisterUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int userId = 0;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert_User"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    userId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            string message = string.Empty;
            switch (userId)
            {
                case -1:
                    message = "Username already exists.\\nPlease choose a different username.";
                    break;
                case -2:
                    message = "Supplied email address has already been used.";
                    break;
                default:
                    message = "Registration successful.\\nUser Id: " + userId.ToString();
                    break;
            }
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile that I get this  :

[image]

> The name 'txtUsername' does not exist in the current context
>
> The name 'txtPassword' does not exist in the current context
>
> The name 'txtEmail' does not exist in the current context

Any idea why this is happening ? the `txtUsername` is declared in the `.aspx` file .

Comment: Can you double-check that all three textboxes are defined in `CS.aspx.designer.cs`?  Normally that is auto-generated by VS, but it can sometimes malfunction.

Comment: Perhaps you have an error in your aspx file that is preventing it from generating the code in the designer.cs file.  Are there any other errors on the page?

Comment: @paqogomez: None , those three are the only ones .

Comment: just curious as to 1 of 2 things.. are you using `MasterPage` and `NameSpace` anywhere in any of the other .cs code behind files..?

Comment: This error could be caused by some non-essential detail. First I'd try to put the validators inside the same table cell.   <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtUsername"
                    runat="server" />
            </td>

Comment: Is this an older project that has been migrated to VS 2012?  It seems odd that you would use the `CodeFile` attribute, which I think was part of the old WebSite Project Type.

Comment: i just created the exact same thing you have, and i can access them... the problem is mostly in the designer file. Open that up and see if they exist... if not, i recommend deleting the web page and creating a new one to remove the problem.

Comment: Same here, I recreated your files and get no error.

Comment: I was able to duplicate his error.  Changing to `CodeBehind` fixed the problem

Comment: @ron, were you able to fix the problem?

Comment: @paqogomez: Working on it .. just came back from work :) I'll get back to you ASAP.

Comment: Great, let me know if there is anything unclear.  I duplicated your problem by creating a webforms page and pasting in your code.  Then changed to `CodeBehind` and was successful.

Comment: @paqogomez: It won't compile , it keeps showing the same `3` errors . It seems that VS refuses to create the designer file.

Comment: You can create it manually, or do as i did, add a new webforms item and paste in overwriting all the code.

Comment: I added steps to creating the file manually.  I tested it myself and it works fine.  My only concern is if you want to keep this in an old format, perhaps targeting an older version of .NET.

Comment: Is this a web application project, or a web site project (File->New Web Site)?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, _I gather_ that he's taking code from a web site project and creating a web forms project.  His code under website works fine, but he doesnt have a .designer.cs file in his new project.

Comment: Where did you gather that from? In any case, I'm trying to teach users of web site projects that they need to specify that they're using them, since those are strange.

Comment: You are an excellent teacher @JohnSaunders, teach on. As for the speculation, it was just that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies in the declaration of the file.  It should look like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" 
       AutoEventWireup="true" 
       CodeBehind="CS.aspx.cs" 
       Inherits="CS" %>
```

Its the .designer.cs file that holds the definition of the aspx objects for the .cs file to use.

By specifying `CodeFile` you were indicating that you were using a Website Project type file instead of a WebForm.

Specify `CodeBehind` instead of `CodeFile`, this will allow VS to add the definition to the .designer.cs file.

EDIT:

If you dont have a .designer file you can create one by:

1. Open the directory where CS.aspx lives.
2. Create a new text file and name it CS.aspx.designer.cs
3. In Visual Studio `show all files` in your project.
4. Drill down into CS.aspx.cs and you'll see your file.
5. Include it in the project.
6. alter something in the CS.aspx file and save it.

This will turn your file into a Webform file.

Looks like @mellamokb had the same idea. :)

Comment: I added the designer file to your answer , much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

The "CS.aspx.designer.cs" file  is missing. Locate the folder where is the CS.apsx and create one text file with the name "CS.aspx.designer.cs"

Comment: Your answer is not necessarily wrong, but a more comprehensive one has already been posted and accepted months ago.